# How to use overprint without adding extra space?

Tags: beamer, spacing

I try to use overprint to show different content on the same slide. Unfortunately, there some extra space is added. How can I avoid this?

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Here the space below this line is smaller ...
    \item Following line 1
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item ... than below here
  \end{itemize}
  \begin{overprint}
    \onslide<1> 
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Following line 2.1
    \end{itemize}
    \onslide<2> 
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Following line 2.2
    \end{itemize}
  \end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**

Here is another example to show that the extra space does not (only?) come from closing the itemize.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test 1}
  Here the space below this line is smaller ...
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Following line 1
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Test 2}
  ... than below here
  \begin{overprint}
    \onslide<1> 
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Following line 2.1
    \end{itemize}
    \onslide<2> 
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Following line 2.2
    \end{itemize}
  \end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The spacing difference is as a result of `overprint` as well. My suggestion is to use the `overprint` environment for your entire `frame` contents.

Comment: @Werner Thanks. I see. For some reason I was under the impression that `overprint` would work properly for environments and paragraphs as well.

Answer (score 3):

The additional space is -- at least partially -- not caused by the overprint, but from closing and opening a new `itemize` environment, you can test this with

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Here the space below this line is smaller ...
    \item Following line 1
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item ... than below here
  \end{itemize}
  \begin{itemize}
      \item Following line 2.1
   \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't need separate itemize environments, I would simply use a single one:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Here the space below this line is smaller ...
    \item Following line 1
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item ... than below here
    \only<1>{\item Following line 2.1}
    \only<2>{\item Following line 2.2}
   \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you have posted the wrong code: it is identical to the OP's one.

Comment: @samcarter Well, I thought that the overprint environment was supposed to do the job as well. If I change only one itemize item it is no problem to use your method. But if I replace several paragraphs and environments this seems a bit cumbersome.

Comment: @Daniel In principal yes, but your space does not come from the overprint, but from closing one itemize environment and then opening another one.

Comment: @samcarter Thanks. But I don't think this is true. I have added an example without closing of itemize.

Comment: @Daniel But it's not entirely wrong either, see the image I added. I think for your new example, you would need to use `\onslide*<1> 
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Following line 2.1
    \end{itemize}}`, otherwise `\onsilde` acts by default like `\visible`. [I personally find `\onslide` a bit confusing and therefore never use it]

Comment: @samcarter I tried the `onslide*` command but that just messed up the entire frame layout.

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, there was a parenthesis missing in my earlier comment `\onslide*<1>{\begin{itemize} \item Following line 2.1 \end{itemize}}`

Comment: @samcarter Thanks. Unfortunately, the `\onslide*` command seems to move the whole text up a bit.